# Proving $x$ between $\alpha - \epsilon$, if $\alpha$ is supremum

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $S\subseteq\Bbb R$ and $\alpha \in \Bbb R$. If $\alpha = \sup(S)$, then show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $x \in S$ such that $\alpha - \epsilon < x$.

**What I have done :**

Since $\alpha$ is the supremum, $x<\alpha$ and $\alpha - \epsilon < \alpha$ I want to show $x$ is in between $\alpha - \epsilon$ and $\alpha$ , but can't and not even sure if it is possible.

Its been a long I posted a question, so sorry if this seems a total homework question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** What happens if there is no $x\in S$ such that $\alpha-\varepsilon<x$? (Think about the definition of supremum).

Answer (score 2):

We want to show the existence of such $x$.

Suppose it doesn't exist, then we have $\alpha - \epsilon$ being an upper bound of $S$ which contradicts that $\alpha$ is the least upper bound.

Comment: Got it, Thanks.